# Determine value of column by iterating over all other columns of dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with columns A-Z and I want to assign the value of Z based on if any other column value is null.
I can do this by:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("Z",
   when(col("A") === lit(null), lit("Y"))
  .when(col("B") === lit(null), lit("Y"))
  .when(col("C") === lit(null), lit("Y"))
  ...
  ...
  .when(col("Y") === lit(null), lit("Y"))
  .otherwise(lit("N")));
```

Is there a more succinct way to iterate over all other columns inside the `withColumn` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by exploring the `spark.sql.functions` package

```
val df2 = df1
  .withColumn("Z",when(array_contains(array(df1.columns.map(c=>lower(col(c))):_*),"null"),lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can iterate over the columns within `withColumns` and use `foldLeft` for the logical expression:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("Z",
      when(
        df.columns
          .filter(name => name.matches("[A-Z]")) // only take these column names
          .map(name => col(name)) // maps String to Column
          .foldLeft(lit(false))((acc, current) => when(acc or current.isNull, lit(true)).otherwise(lit(false)))
        , lit("Y"))
        .otherwise(lit("N"))
    )
```

Test:

input:

```
+---+----+----+
|  A|   B|   C|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   2|   3|
|  1|null|   3|
|  1|null|null|
+---+----+----+
```

output:

```
+---+----+----+---+
|  A|   B|   C|  Z|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|   2|   3|  N|
|  1|null|   3|  Y|
|  1|null|null|  Y|
+---+----+----+---+
```

Comment: I tried with this, actually I have 272 columns and not just `A-Z` which I had put for simplicity. So on a 1.5 million rows dataset `foldLeft` is not working out, spark job continued for 5 hours before I terminated it.